# 100% CPU usage after deployments

Tags: magento2, cache, performance, deployment

After deploying change to magento cloud (2.4.3p3) our servers are hitting 100% CPU, which makes the whole system unresponsive and inaccessible. It seems to last random amount of time can be more than 30 minutes before the system recovers. Is this kind of behaviour normal?

Happens consistently after deploying changes to staging & production environments but also, clearing a single cache (even just for CMS updates) results in making our production environment unresponsive due to high CPU usage. This means that we can't actually deploy to production without significant downtime currently.

I've found many threads about high usage on cache but most seem to be related to people disabling cache for development environments.
Are there any settings/configuration that I can check which have a large impact on cache performance?

Comment: Additional DB information request just BEFORE deploying changes, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Additional DB information request gathered 15 minutes after deploying changes, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis of extreme activity since deploy to provide suggestions.    Name of cloud provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be related to caching performance issues within magento 2.4.3 version. Once we had upgraded to magento 2.4.6, which included several performance related fixes/improvements this caching issue was resolved.

It seems one of the main fixes was around cache generation for example: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/31879